# Swift Playground: NSXMLParser / parse() always returns false

Tags: xcode, swift, parsing, nsxmlparser, swift-playground

here's my code:

```
public class Payment: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate {

public var buchungsdatum:NSDate
public var valutadatum:NSDate
public var betrag:Double
public var verwendungszweck:String

public var creditorIban:String
public var creditorBic:String
public var creditorName:String

public var debitorIban:String
public var debitorBic:String
public var debitorName:String

override init() {
    buchungsdatum = NSDate()
    valutadatum = NSDate()
    betrag = 0.0
    verwendungszweck = ""

    creditorIban = ""
    creditorBic = ""
    creditorName = ""

    debitorBic = ""
    debitorIban = ""
    debitorName = ""
}

override public var description: String {
    return "Payment-Information:"
}

func beginParse() {
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/Andi/Downloads/c53/CAMT/2015-10-06_C53_DE92300606010303502481_EUR_585142.xml")

    let xml = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)!

    xml.delegate = self
    xml.parse()

}

@objc public func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    print("get an element")
}

@objc public func parserDidStartDocument(parser: NSXMLParser) {
    print("started")
}


@objc public func parserDidEndDocument(parser: NSXMLParser) {
    print("ended")
}

public func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError) {
    print("Fehler")
}
} 
var aPayment:Payment = Payment()
aPayment.beginParse()
```

Can anyone tell me why the parse() returns false and none of the delegate methods get called. Even the parseError one doesn't. I absolutely don't understand why.

Xcode even shows that the XML-File has content and that url isn't nil (see pic)
[Xcode shows the XMLContent in the playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PgyN.png)

Comment: First thing to ask yourself: is `url` nil?

Comment: "and that makes me angry" Whoa, okay, I just stopped helping.

Comment: No, url is not nil (see picture)

Comment: Ok, good. Second question, is it valid XML?  Please post the actual file somewhere so we can examine.

Comment: Yep, it's very valid. It's a statement file from a bank. Sorry, can't post it (data security), but trust me, it's valid. It works when I hard code it as a string variable, but that's not want to do.

Comment: Next: Try running your code in a real app, not a playground.

Comment: Oh, one more idea.  Load the NSData from the Url yourself and call init data instead of init contentsOfUrl.

Comment: Just tried to load the contents into a String via "contentsOfURL" and gives me the error 257 (no permission to view (the file?)). Wow... that was it? Thanks for the help anyways, very appreciated.

Comment: So I think in the playground there a some restrictions, right? Will try it in a real app project then.

Answer (score -2):

It is most likely because your NSURL is nil.

Comment: Don't post comments as answers.

Comment: url is not nil, just look at the picture.